# PHP code to access API of a Java library

Tags: java, php, opennlp

I need to use the *Java*-based OpenNLP library in my *PHP* code. For example, I need to use its Sentence Detector component (en-sent.bin) for analysing text variables in my PHP code.

In its [documentation](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.detection.cmdline), that API can be accessed from a *Java* code as follows:

```
InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-sent.bin");

try {
  SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  if (modelIn != null) {
    try {
      modelIn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

How can do the same thing in *PHP*?

In other words, what is the *PHP*-equivalent to the above *Java* code?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I'm about to implement is writing a java based backend (because just the OpenNLP tool's output just won't cut it) and using PHP's execute function to run it. If you want it to be even faster, I suggest making it a daemon, making PHP connect to it and send it data to return (it'd probably be a unix socket). Although it's kinda complex, it seems less error prone than a PHP/Java Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

There would have to be a PHP API for accessing OpenNLP. A quick search doesn't show anything. The only other thing I can think of is using a PHP/Java Bridge of some sort, but that's more involved. See http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/, for example.